# Match Items between two Lightswitch Queries

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have a tile list in a HTML Lightswitch Client (current version) and want to enable functionality for users to be able to click an element and display the addEdit screen for that element.

The addEdit screen uses a query `Complaints` and the tile list uses a query `vw_Upcoming_Complaints`. Both queries have a common unique attribute `Complant_ID`.

I currently have the following code:

```
myapp.Main.vw_Upcoming_Complaints_Selected_execute = function (screen) {
    myapp.showAddEditComplaints(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addEditComplaintScreen) {
            addEditComplaintScreen.Complaint = screen.Upcoming_Complaints.selectedItem;
        },
        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            screen.selected_Complaint.details.refresh();
        }
    });
};
```

Lightswitch currently shows the correct `Complaint_ID` on the addEdit screen but does not fetch the remainder of the attributes.

How can I tell lightswitch that the common identifier is `complaint_Id` and it should find the rest of the attributes in the `Complaints` data set?

There is no way for me to edit the original `Complaints` query to contain all the attributes of the `vw_Upcoming_Work` dataset.

Comment: Did my proposed answer help to provide a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to update your vw_Upcoming_Complaints_Selected_execute function along the following lines:

```
myapp.Main.vw_Upcoming_Complaints_Selected_execute = function (screen) {
    myapp.showAddEditComplaint(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addEditComplaintScreen) {
            var id = screen.Upcoming_Complaints.selectedItem.Id;
            myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Complaints_SingleOrDefault(id).execute().then(function onComplete(result) {
                if (result && result.results && result.results.length !== 0) {
                    addEditComplaintScreen.Complaint = result.results[0];
                }
            });
        },
        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            screen.selected_Complaint.details.refresh();
        }
    });
};
```

This update assumes that your DataSource is called ApplicationData, and the complaint id is the key of your Complaints query.

Based upon these assumptions, the revised version simply locates the matching Complaint entity, by using the _SingleOrDefault method against your Complaints query, and assigns it to the add edit screen.

Comment: Apologies for not marking this as the answer. This worked perfectly. Thanks.